# Passing arguments from command line in excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, command-line

I have found several snippet of code out there that allows me to pass arguments into excel from command line.

The code below is placed in a new module called parameters:

```
Declare Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As Long
Declare Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As Long)

Public CmdLineToStr() As String
'
' Returns the command line in the call to Excel
'
Dim Buffer() As Byte
Dim StrLen As Long
Dim CmdPtr As Long

CmdPtr = GetCommandLineW()
If CmdPtr > 0 Then
  StrLen = lstrlenW(CmdPtr) * 2
  If StrLen > 0 Then
    ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
    CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal CmdPtr, StrLen
    CmdLineToStr = Buffer
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

and then in thisworkbook i call this code

```
Sub workBook_open()
    MsgBox Parameters.CmdLineToStr
End Sub
```

It fails with the `GetCommandLine` function, so is the  error due to problems with linking the dll library or  is this due to the fact that i have some macros stored in personal.xlsb?

I call the excel sheet from the command line with this line:

`C:\Users\kim\Desktop>start excel Parameters.xlsm /e/nmbnmbmnb`

and i get this error :

[image: eroor]

[Outside procedure](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/179919-invalid-outside-procedure.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The corrected, **tested** procedure:  (The version above had two mistakes.)

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As Long
Declare Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As Long)

Public Function CmdLineToStr() As String
'Returns the command line used to open Excel
    Dim Buffer() As Byte, StrLen As Long, CmdPtr As Long
    CmdPtr = GetCommandLine()
    If CmdPtr > 0 Then
      StrLen = lstrlenW(CmdPtr) * 2
      If StrLen > 0 Then
        ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
        CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal CmdPtr, StrLen
        CmdLineToStr = Buffer
      End If
    End If
End Function
```

...place the code in a new, regular module, then call `CmdLineToStr` to get the command line that was used to open Excel, such as:

```
excel.exe /x "C:\Users\someone\Desktop\myTest.xlsm"
```

Comment: I have copied the same code but  lstrlenW(CmdPtr) -> this is giving me zero so nothing is working after this

Answer (score 3):

Change `Public CmdLineToStr() As String`

to `Public Function CmdLineToStr() As String`

`Public CmdLineToStr() As String` is not a procedure, you need to put either `Sub` or `Function` so it is a procedure.  Hence the error message "Invalid outside procedure" because you were precisely outside a procedure.

Comment: Thanks, It works nicely now. Now i can start splitting the parameters and do some useful stuff:)