# Run Excel VBA/Macro from Shell by Providing Path Argument

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

I have an Excel VBA script that is in `.xlsm` format. Once the file is opened, a window pops up asking you to "Browse" for file and provide the address to the file in a text box.

I want to run this `.xlsm` file from `cmd` and provide the path argument to it from cmd as well.

How can I do this?

This opens the file:

> EXCEL.EXE /e "c:\converter.xlsm"

But I cannot figure out how to **pass a path argument** and **hit the submit button** all from cmd.

Comment: Check out this post here on StackOverflow. it explains it all
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405654/passing-arguments-from-command-line-in-excel-2010

Answer (score 0):

xlsm files can only be opened by excel and VBA stants for visual basic for applications, you can write Visual Basic script and execute it from dos prompt (.vbs files ) also more information on the issue is on [microsoft technet library on vb script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156587.aspx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file?rq=1