# Workbook_Open event erroneously triggered when linking to xlsm workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

I am running a [Edit] read-only (3rd party!) [/Edit] SQL database, an xlsm, an xls (saved copy of the xlsm, just without macros), and an mdb (Access database).

They are linked as follows:

- The xlsm gets data from the SQL database every 5 minutes by Application.OnTime code, triggered on Workbook_Open.
- The xlsm then saves itself as a 2003 xls.
- Since the code modules still exist at that moment (the workbook is not yet closed), I can open the Access mdb and refresh the Excel link to a table in the 2003 data, then close Access.
- I then reopen the xlsm, triggering a new Application.Ontime instance.
- I finally close the 2003 xls workbook.

This sequence runs during office hours and at the first run after 5pm sets a timer to start the process again in the morning.

My problem is whenever I open a file with a connection or link to the xlsm, the Workbook_Open event seems to trigger and I end up with the 2003 xls open on the 'client' computers. I know it's not just a leftover Application.OnTime on mine (the PC I originally created the files on) because now it's in use and other clients who have never opened the xlsm get the 2003 file randomly popping up when they're using Excel.

If that's not enough to trigger someone to know what's going on, I'll happily post code - but I am hoping someone has seen this before or knows of this rookie mistake and can simply give me a line I'm missing.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Open the workbook by disabling events using `application.enableevents = false`. this wont trigger the workbook open event

Comment: I had something a bit similar. We use a tool that keeps our local clients in sync with the server version of all our files. We usually get conflict on files we didn't actually open, but are linked from another file. So in the background on some level that file is actually opened, which in your case would trigger the `Workbook_Open` event

Comment: @TanmayGawankar then you would need to do this on every file that has data linked to his XLSM file. Making all those files xlsm files.  jfgoodhwe1: Wouldn't it be easier to simply have your other files link data from the 2003 file?

Comment: @TanmayGawankar Thank you, but I don't actually open the workbook, it's using Get Data button or just an equals formula directed to the xls workbook.

Comment: @Luuklag I actually just had the exact same thought, and have changed my formula reference now to the 2003 xls. I'll also change the data reference when I find it and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: It seems a really long way to get data from SQL into Access (I'm presuming that's what you are trying to achieve here?). Could you not just link Access to SQL to get your data?

Comment: @Zac Unfortunately there is data processing from the raw data in the SQL database (our stock storage system which is read only - forgot to mention that part!). We also have a 3rd party application (CAD system) that can only access XLS files (not xlsm) because they're still using JET drivers... But to keep it as brief as I could I omitted that peripheral. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Luuklag if you pose your point on linking to the 2003 file as an answer, I will mark it as an answer - turned out to be an easy noob one, but you can have the rep since yours was the best answer :)

Comment: @jfgoodhew1 I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to have all other files link to the `.xls` file, instead of the `.xlsm` macro enabled file. Downside to this approach would be that you have to (manually) update all your references.

Answer (score 2):

I would think the reason the XLS pops up on your clients is because Excel has to open the linked XLSM in order to access the data, and as such, `Workbook_Open` gets triggered.

A few alternatives to the suggestions you have in the comments;

- Check `Environ("Username")` before executing `Application.OnTime` so that it will only run if the file is opened by specific users.
- Use a launcher-file to open the XLSM in "admin mode" - you can do this by using the launcher-file to set a `Global`-scope variable, and then have the XLSM check this variable before running `Application.OnTime`.
- Make the XLSM test for some dummy-file on the local computer - one that you easily can create by hand on the computer you need regular access to the XLSM on. For example the XLSM can look for `C:\Data\xlsm-enabler.txt` or whatever works, and only run the relevant macro if the file exists.
- Similar to the above, use [`SaveSetting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/savesetting-statement) to set a registry key on the "admin" machine(s) and check against this inside the XLSM.
- Set your XLSM up to [accept parameters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb9fa94f-a1d4-45cd-9279-b12e7a7e69c0/passing-a-parameter-to-an-excel-file-when-opening-it?forum=excel), and use such parameters to open the file in "admin mode". This method is outlined several other places @ SO, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405654/passing-arguments-from-command-line-in-excel-2010).
- This is more of a hunch - you might be able to leverage the [Workbook.ReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.readonly) property in your XLSM as a conditional. This assumes that Excel opens the XLSM in readonly-mode when accessing it via data connections, which I don't know whether is actually the case.

Comment: Excellent ideas @Vegard thank you. I haven't seen the xls pop up since I switched my references to the 2003 version, but I wouldn't be surprised if it comes back sometime. I almost answered someone else's similar query once with a global variable option, but wasn't sure the distinction between global and public so let it be. I'm bookmarking the option to set up my xlsm to accept parameters, that sounds very cool. Thanks so much for a wonderful response! I'll leave it open for 24hrs but unfortunately if it works the answer has to go to the simplest earlier option of referencing my XLS instead..

Comment: The distinction between `Global` and `Public` is only minute, they do practically the same. One is old, one is newer. And of course you should mark the best answer as "the" answer - that's how StackOverflow works :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be way easier to do everything in Access. Then if you need to represent the data in Excel you can have a Workbook with a link to the Access table. This removes a step and it uses the right tool for the job. Access is for linking to database tables. Excel is for processing data views.

`SQL > Access > Excel`

Comment: Indeed it would be, if only I knew how to use it. There is definitely a place for using the right tool for the job, am glad you advised this. I hope to move into an MRP system by the time that happens, and link that way.

Comment: Create a new blank database in Access. Click `External Data > New Data Source > From Database > From SQL Server` In the wizard: select `Link to the data source by creating a linked table`. If you don't have a DSN file from the DBA click `New...` Select `SQL Server`, next, name the file. Then configure the SQL connection.