# Passing in Parameters to Workbook_Activate from Command Line

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to keep alive an old Excel VBA program, and my client has asked me to run some existing code on startup (instead of having to click a button).

So, I'm following this tutorial [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/01/25/command-line-arguments-in-vba/).

It kinda works ... ie when the excel files is open the MsgBox prompts appear but with blanks or 0s. However that only happens when I don't include the first line:

`Declare Function GetCommandLineA Lib "Kernel32" () As String`

when I include that, I get this error message:

> *Compile Error: Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules.*

So - how do I do it?

The `Sub Workbook_Activate` is `Private` and I don't think I can change that, can I?

Comment: You need to put it in a **standard module** not in an  *object module* like *class module* or `ThisWorkbook`. That is what the error says.

Comment: yes, but how I do I get Workbook_Activate to be a standard module?

Comment: you don't! `Workbook_Activate` needs to be in `ThisWorkbook` but the `Declare Function GetCommandLineA Lib "Kernel32" () As String` needs to be in a standard module. The error is only compaining about this one line.

Comment: can you please point me in the direction of what i am trying to do? ie, read parameters when they're passed in via the command line?

Comment: I don't understand your question. To get rid of the error just put this line `Declare Function GetCommandLineA Lib "Kernel32" () As String` into a standard module. That's all.

Comment: i can do that, but then how is that standard module called automatically when the excel sheet opens?   (sorry, I haven't written VBA in over a decade)

Comment: Therefor you have your `Workbook_Activate` or `Workbook_open` event in `ThisWorkbook`. • Note that your tutorial is for the ancient Excel 97 so if you use a newer version I recommend to have a look here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405654/passing-arguments-from-command-line-in-excel-2010

Comment: ok thanks ... I'll check that out   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting for other confused people:

I was trying to run it from within the ThisWorkbook sub, and what Pᴇʜ rightly pointed out was that you have to create this code in a normal module, and then call that module's sub FROM the ThisWorkbook sub.

thank you Pᴇʜ